# How to implement paging in Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I need to paginate a collection of articles (order by date - and nothing else). What is the standard way doing something like this in Mongodb?

I am not going to use the skip() method because of performance issues. Neither do I plan to use the $push method. The closest method I have seen is the range query method. But it seems to fail if any of the sorted items are removed.

Answer (score 10):

Range sorting should work well for you. First request will take first 10 items sorted by date:

```
db.articles.find({}).sort( { date : -1 } ).limit(10);
```

After this you will need store somewhere date of last item and use id in next paging request:

```
db.articles.find({"date": {$lt: storedDateOfLastItem}}).sort( { date : -1 } ).limit(10);
```

So, i guess it should work well for you. To estimate total count of pages you will need to use [count](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%7B%7Bcount%28%29%7D%7D).

> But it seems to fail if any of the sorted items are removed.

If you will remove for example article from page #1 it for sure break page #2 because of stored last date will be changed. To avoid this you can estimate count of items that was before current saved date

```
db.articles.find({"date": {$gt: storedDateOfLastItem}}).sort( { date : -1 } ).count()
```

If this count was changed (let say 2 articled was removed). You need to updated `storedDateOfLastItem`

```
db.articles.find({"date": {$gt: storedDateOfLastItem}}).sort( { date : -1 } ).take(2)
```

Again taking storedDateOfLastItem from last item of above request and continue make paging.

But my opinion just keep this paging as it is without extra logic, because i suppose that article deletion is rare operation.

From mongodb documentation:

> Paging Costs Unfortunately skip can be (very) costly and requires the
>   server to walk from the beginning of the collection, or index, to get
>   to the offset/skip position before it can start returning the page of
>   data (limit). As the page number increases skip will become slower and
>   more cpu intensive, and possibly IO bound, with larger collections.
>
> Range based paging provides better use of indexes but does not allow
>   you to easily jump to a specific page.

Comment: Range queries/page markers using date types do not work since you will get inconsistencies for multiple records with the same date. I would use _id value markers instead for this. All that said this is a ton of housekeeping just to avoid o(N) performance for skip(N).

Comment: Ahhhh is paging so tedious in mongodb? I wish someone from 10gen show us how they recommend paging.

Comment: @LulZilla: Look at my update, it is from mongodb documentation.

Comment: where would you store `storedDateOfLastItem`?

Comment: You'd have to store it in the session so that you can track where each user is in their pagin

Comment: This sucks. How would I jump a user to an arbitrary page?

Answer (score 0):

If you can sort on an index, efficient pagination can be implemented using the "$min" and "$max" query modifiers or a range query. Make sure your index includes a unique property at the end (eg. "_id").

If you can't sort on an index, you could pre-process the full set of results and keep a list of the "_id" values in order. You could then take a range of that list and find a page of results using the "$in" query operator.