# get json data from java-mongo driver(not list of BasicDataObject)

Tags: java, json, mongodb

I am doing following in my application server,

```
  DBCollection collection = mongoDB.getCollection("collection"); 
  DBCursor dbCursor = collection.find();
```

I have to send a JSON object to the client from the server, so how can 
I convert DBCursor Object to JSON.

Actually i am sending a large collection to client, and if i convert documents of this collection into java object than it eat lot of memory, so if there a way to convert dbcursor direct to json string , or any other method which solve my problem.
it will be great help.
Thanks.

Its look like mongodriver create DataObject's objects, when call find method, so it will not help to convert dbcursor into json (which is possible by using serialize() method of com.mongodb.util.JSON class.

Revise Question:

is there any way to get data of a collection directly without using find method.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to convert the cursor to a JSON String, the cursor is simply a way to iterate over the values returned from find.

Asking if there's a way to get data from the collection without using "find" is a bit like asking how to get data from a SQL database without querying it - you can't.  At some point you have to make a call to the database to get the data you want.  In the MongoDB Java driver, this is done via the find() method.  If you want to limit the amount of objects returned (not surprisingly a whole collection could take a lot of memory), then you want to [pass the query details into the find method](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-java-driver/#getting-a-single-document-with-a-query) to filter your results.

However, if you are working exclusively with JSON, you might want to investigate third party libraries like [MongoJack](http://mongojack.org/) - this uses the Java driver under the covers, but translates the results of your query directly into JSON for you.

Comment: you are right about using find method, but it interally convert bason result into DBObjects, i just want to prevent it and want to get this bason data(json prefred) directly by implement drivers methods which communicate to the db interally. right now i am looking for the solution. because when i get all document of that collection, it took lot of memory approx-200mb which are not desirable. if you already have any solution of this type or any other solution, please help me.

Comment: The answer is that you can't get all the data back, for exactly the reason you say - you can't keep it all in memory.  It's standard practice to page the results, i.e. pull back a set of data (say a hundred), return those, then fetch the next batch, and return those and so on.  There is no way to get around the fact that pulling all the results into memory will take up a lot of memory.  You've given low-level details of what you want, but can you give the higher level view?  E.g. "trying to return full list of customers via a rest api"?

Comment: And when I say paging is the standard way of doing this, this applies to SQL databases as well as Mongo.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8383488/how-to-implement-paging-in-mongodb for an example

Comment: Thanks for reply. yes you are right about do paging of result most of time, but in my requirement i have to send some masters data to rest client, like list of doctors, list of medicine, country database etc. and my clients are heavy one which can store some data locally and process it. so i am send whole bunch of collection at same time, thats why i need store data, return from mongodb into one jsonstring, which still save in memory but less than what if store in java objects.

Comment: Then perhaps look at selecting only the fields you want from the database instead of every field in the document, reducing the amount of memory required?  There's not getting away from the fact that if you're building a big JSON string from a lot of objects, you will need a lot of memory.